# DC JS: remove outer padding for line charts with an ordinal scale x-axis?

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js, linechart, crossfilter

I built a line chart using DC JS with an ordinal x-axis. It works, except that there is some outer padding on the x-axis that I can't seem to get rid of. I'd like the left-most and right-most data points to be flush with the edges of the chart, with no padding. Hopefully I'm not missing something obvious.

I think I'm setting up the x-axis scale incorrectly. Given a data set like this:

```
var data = [
  { key: 'Monday', value: 3000000 },
  { key: 'Tuesday', value: 3100000 },
  { key: 'Wednesday', value: 3500000 },
  { key: 'Thursday', value: 3070000 },
  { key: 'Friday', value: 4500000 },
  { key: 'Saturday', value: 3003030 },
  { key: 'Sunday', value: 5010000 }
];
```

Here's what I'm doing with the x-axis scale:

```
var ordinalScale = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']).rangeRoundBands([0,chartWidth]);
chart.x(ordinalScale).xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
```

I've also looked at the D3 documentation on ordinal scales, but that hasn't helped yet.

Here's a screen shot (extraneous padding marked in red):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUNeV.jpg

Here's a working JS fiddle that demonstrates the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/qvp4fpzy/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little confusing dealing with both dc.js and d3.js features around range bands.

dc.js has its own built-in calculations for bar/line x positions, but if the x scale is ordinal, it automatically chooses `.rangeBands`:

```
    if (_chart.isOrdinal()) {
        _x.rangeBands([0, _chart.xAxisLength()], _rangeBandPadding,
                      _chart._useOuterPadding() ? _outerRangeBandPadding : 0);
    } else // ...
```

[source link](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/356fccea3a1dbd49a76fb1841f280ffad87d725f/src/coordinate-grid-mixin.js#L475-L477)

So I don't think your call to `.rangeRoundBands` has any effect. (Should dc.js use `rangeRoundBands` instead of `rangeBands`? Maybe, but it doesn't weight on this question.)

It's the [third parameter to `rangeBands`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Ordinal-Scales.md#ordinal_rangeBands) that you want to influence, and that's controlled by `chart._outerRangeBandPadding()`. (Ignore `chart._useOuterPadding()` - that's a backward compatibility thing.)

So all you need here is

```
chart._outerRangeBandPadding(0);
```

[image: no outer padding]

[Working fork of your fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/6x8oqgst/5/)